# Does the idiom "in the light of" exist?

Tags: idioms, academia

In Portuguese we say *à luz de*, which is close to *based on*, but more sophisticated. It is mostly used in academic writings. I'd translate it as *in the light of*, but I know we can hardly ever translate idioms. Here's a sentence it might apply:

> He developed his ideas in the light of Einstein's work.

Can I use this? If not, then could you tell me some ways to say this? Thanks.

Comment: ["Standing on the shoulders of giants"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stand+on+the+shoulders+of+giants&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=n-yoWJW_O-Gw8we25JaoCQ) comes to mind-

Comment: @Cascabel Like Newton. But that's too strong, and I'm talking about one specific author. It doesn't seem to fit in quite.

Comment: Yes, "in the light of" can be used in this way.

Comment: The only time I can recall this usage in English is from the Herbert book "Dune": "I congratulate you on the perfection of your heir... _in the light of_  the elder, one might say."...and it was ambiguous in context. It is possible there is a usage in academia which is suitable.

Comment: It's true that many idioms don't jump straight across to another language; but it sometimes surprises me how many do carry over. So don't be afraid to look up your idea in a dictionary of idioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly:

> in the light of

There is no great difference in *in the light of* and  *à luz de*,

But in English your sentence might better be written:

> In the light of Einstein's work, he developed his ideas.

A similar idiom in English *in light of* , generally means "given the fact(or facts) of":

> In light of his confession, he had little defense.

Answer (score 1):

> "**in the light of something   (British & Australian)**
>
> also **in light of something (American & Australian)**
>
> If something is done or happens in the light of facts, it is done or
>   happens because of those facts.
>
> *In the light of new evidence he has been allowed to appeal against his prison sentence.*
>
> *In light of what you've just told me, I can understand why you and
>   David were fighting.*"

(http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+light+of)